# How to make language preference be applied immediately?

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I've managed to create the switch preference allowing me to enable and disable the language, however I cannot apply the changes immediately after the option has been selected.

```
<PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Language">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:title="@string/setting_enable"
        android:key="checkbox_Lang"
        android:summaryOn="@string/settings_sum_en"
        android:summaryOff="@string/settings_sum_dis"
        android:defaultValue="false"/>

</PreferenceCategory>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

The code below is what i used to change the language settings.

```
private void loadPreferences(){
    //allows to get the preferances from any screen in the application
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    boolean isEngChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checkbox_Lang",false);
    if (isEngChecked){

        String languageToLoad  = "Default"; //selected the default language (English)
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    } else {

        String languageToLoad  = "ar"; // your language
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    }

}
```

How can i change my code to allow the change to happen immediately?

P.s i've tried to recreate to activity however this creates more problems when the application is opened after it is closed (displays white screen).

Comment: Why switch languages in your application?  Unless you're a keyboard, its  easier to let them switch it in the global language settings.

Comment: I never really thought of that, how would you go about doing this? @GabeSechan

Comment: Intent i = new Intent( android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS );
startActivity( i );     That will launch the global settings menu for locale.

Comment: ahh yes i see what that does however i would only like the application to switch from two languages, my problem however is that the activity does not immediately update, how can i make it possible? @GabeSechan